# initialize an array of events, win32,ada

Tags: multithreading, winapi, events, ada

I need to cheate array of events with win32 help. Language: Ada.

What I do:

```
p:integer := 4;
Type EvArr1 is array (1..p) of HANDLE;

procedure Start (Tid : in integer) is
       Task T1;
        task body T1 is
            Bl:bool;
            temp:Dword;
            ...
        begin
                        ...
            Bl:=(EvArr1(Tid));
            temp:=WaitForMultipleObjects(EvArr1, infinite);
                        ...
    end T1;
end start;
BEGIN
        ...
    for i in 1..p loop
        EvArr1(i) := CreateEvent(null, 1, 0, null); -- error
        EvArr2(i) := CreateEvent(null, 1, 0, null); -- error
        start(i);
    end loop;
```

Error:

> The types are not convertible; the operand type must be an array type, Continuing

Comment: More Information needed for a full diagnosis. Most likely your CreateEvent function is not returning something of type HANDLE.

Comment: ps, your tasking looks a little strange too, suggest you read this (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Tasking)

Answer (score 1):

As declared, `EvArr1` is a type, not an object.

Try

```
EvArr1 : array (1 .. p) of HANDLE;
```

or

```
type Event_Array is array (1 .. p) of HANDLE;
EvArr1 : Event_Array;
```

The second is good if you want to have subprograms/entries with parameters of the type. Even better,

```
type Event_Array is array (Positive range <>) of HANDLE;
EvArr1 : Event_Array (1 .. p);
```